# Why is my loaded nib crashing when memory is released?

Tags: iphone

If I run Build and Analyze this loads without errors according to the Analyzer but the app crashes. If I remove the `[myStates release];` analyzer complains about possible leak but the nib loads and runs just fine. MyStateList is a nib which has a pickerview inside that loads a plist if this helps. Please help.

## Main TrialViewControllerViewController Implementation File

```
#import "TrialViewControllerViewController.h"
#import "MyStateList.h"

@implementation TrialViewControllerViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

MyStateList *myStates = [[MyStateList alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyStateList" bundle:nil];    
[self.view addSubview:[myStates view]];  
//[myStates release];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
}


- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Here is what i am trying to load

## MyStateList.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyStateList : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,  UIPickerViewDataSource> {

UIPickerView   *pickerView;
NSMutableArray *statesArray;   // Written array
NSDictionary   *stateListDictionary,*stateListDictionaries;
NSArray  *firstDisplayArray,*updateDisplayArray,*switchDisplayArray;
NSInteger  dTag;
NSString *nott,*verify,*notes;

IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne,*labelTwo,*labelThree,*labelName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *pickerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary  *stateListDictionary,*stateListDictionaries;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray     *firstDisplayArray,*updateDisplayArray,*switchDisplayArray; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelOne,*labelTwo,*labelThree,*labelName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nott,*verify,*notes;

- (void)loadData;
- (void)placeData;
- (void)createPicker;

@end
```

## MyStateList.m

```
#import "MyStateList.h"

@implementation MyStateList
@synthesize pickerView;
@synthesize  stateListDictionary,stateListDictionaries,firstDisplayArray,updateDisplayArray,switchDisplayArray ;
@synthesize labelOne,labelTwo,labelThree,labelName;
@synthesize nott,verify,notes;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self createPicker];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{ 
return [statesArray count];
}


-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerViewCust viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

NSString *rowItem = [statesArray objectAtIndex: row];
UILabel *lblRow = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerViewCust bounds].size.width, 44.0f)]autorelease];
[lblRow setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor]];
[lblRow setText:rowItem];
[lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
return lblRow;
}

- (void)createPicker 
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"StateArray" ofType:@"plist"];

stateListDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
labelName.text     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Arizona"];
[self loadData];    
float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float pickerWidth = screenWidth * 1 / 2;
float xPoint = screenWidth / 2 - pickerWidth / 1;
pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
[pickerView setDataSource: self];
[pickerView setDelegate: self];
[pickerView setFrame: CGRectMake(xPoint, 280.0f, pickerWidth, 180.0f)];
pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview: pickerView];
}

- (void)loadData 
{

firstDisplayArray = [stateListDictionary objectForKey:@"Arizona"];
dTag = 1;
[self placeData];   
stateListDictionary = nil;  // kill the list
statesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[statesArray addObject:@"Alabama"];
[statesArray addObject:@"Alaska"];
[statesArray addObject:@"Arizona"];
[statesArray addObject:@"Arkansas"];
[statesArray addObject:@"California"];  
}

- (void)placeData 
{

if (dTag == 1) 
{
    switchDisplayArray = firstDisplayArray;
    dTag = 0;

} else {
    switchDisplayArray = updateDisplayArray;
}

nott     = [switchDisplayArray objectAtIndex:0];
verify   = [switchDisplayArray objectAtIndex:1];
notes    = [switchDisplayArray objectAtIndex:2];

labelOne.text      = nott;
labelTwo.text      = verify;
labelThree.text    = notes;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"StateArray" ofType:@"plist"];

stateListDictionaries = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
labelName.text = [statesArray objectAtIndex: row];
updateDisplayArray = [stateListDictionaries objectForKey:labelName.text];
[self placeData];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
[pickerView release];
[stateListDictionary release];
[stateListDictionaries release];
[statesArray release];
[super dealloc];


}


@end
```

Comment: How does your `MyStateList` class look like?

Comment: UPDATE YOUR QUESTION WITH CRASH LOG. Be specific when you say Crash, there can be so many reasons why your application crashed.

Comment: @0x8badf00d The app does not load. Session window shows nothing but time session started, and a break point shows --> Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” –

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, if you search in google or in stack overflow on how to find root cause: Set NSZombieEnabled to YES and see to which released object you are sending message to. Then if it points to [myStates release] then increase scope of myStates variable from local to Class by making it an ivar and release in dealloc method instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, `MyStatesList` is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

If you release `myStates` at the end of the block, you're essentially removing the brain from your view controller, but leaving its body there. You need to keep the controller itself around as well as the view, as the view is owned by the controller. Not the other way around.

The view from your view controller is retained by the view, but you killed the view controller itself. The bigger problem is you CAN'T just add views from UIViewControllers in this manner. On iOS5 you have the ability to use `addChildViewController:` and prior to that you can use one of the provided container controllers.

Comment: I've been pointed your way by Craig, and i will try what you have suggested. I posted the code and have one question for you. Do I need to nil the deallocated Arrays inside of dealloc? or is releasing them enough. Thanks for your help

Comment: Nilling is not strictly needed in dealloc, although I prefer the self.property = nil style of cleaning up.

Comment: I am programing for the iphone and I have SDK 4.2. is this enough to use: addChildViewController? I am still searching for a container controller... does this mean you can place a controller inside of a UIView?

Comment: Oh so that explains it. I have to pay a developers fee to get that right? Is it just $99 a year or are there startup fees as well?

Answer (score 1):

**You do indeed need to release your `MyStateList` object.**

Here's what's happening:

1. You initialize a new `MyStateList`, which has a retain count of 1
2. You add a subview to your view, and that subview is **NOT** the `MyStateList` object, but the ivar `view` of your `MyStateList` object.
3. When you don't release your `myStates` object, you are *indeed leaking this object*, since nothing has a reference to this object anymore, and the memory was never deallocated. (Its retain count never reached 0.)

That having been said, what kind of error occurs when your application crashes? I'm guessing that `MyStateList` is a `UIViewController`, and the view is then attempting to access/communicate with its parent, which has been released/deallocated.

Comment: The app does not load. Session window shows nothing but time session started, and a break point shows --> Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` indicates, usually, that you're accessing memory that has been deallocated. We need to know more information about your `MyStateList` object. Is it a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Yes it's a UIViewController and i just posted the code. Sorry for the delay I worked today and it took me a while to learn how to edit the post.

Comment: @hodji In that case, you should take a closer look at the answer from Joshua Weinberg which seems to address your issue pretty specifically.

Answer (score 1):

In your `-(void)dealloc;` you are calling `[super dealloc]` first, this is wrong. Make it the last call in the method. This should fix your crash.

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
// Wrong Way
[super dealloc];
[pickerView release];
[stateListDictionary release];
[stateListDictionaries release];
[statesArray release];
}
```

`

```
- (void)dealloc 
{
// Right way
[pickerView release];
[stateListDictionary release];
[stateListDictionaries release];
[statesArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Your right about the ordering, typo from cutting and pasting. I fixed that, but the app still  has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you add the view [myStates view], to the controller's view, so the view is hold by the controller's view.

then you release "myStates" for avoid memeory leak, it is removed.

and I guess in your view [myStates view], there must be some delegates related to the object "myState", but it was removed just before. So, the app crash.

To avoid both problems, memory leak and crash. I think you should make the "myStates" hold by your controller as a member variable. And you could release "myState" when your viewUnloaded.

Comment: This sounds like where i was headed next. My problem is i don't know how to turn it into a variable. MyStateList *myStates. MyStateList is a subclass and if i make myState a property variable it does not work infront of ... MyStatList. I tried: <code> MyStateList myState = [[MyStateList alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyStateList" bundle:nil];</code> With myState as a property variable to no avail. – –